# how to break elements in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have an element in follow list as:

```
  [0.29839835, [734, 805, 679, 758], 'A']
```

I need to change it to

```
  [0.29839835, 734, 805, 679, 758, 'A']
```

Just break the inner set of elements [734, 805, 679, 758] from one elements to 4 elements. Any leads pls?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, is there a better dupe target? While the target has 49 answers, not one of them has the `itertools` solution, and indeed it's probably because the question there is more generalized. In which case, my answer below wouldn't fit on that question.

Comment: @jpp 3 solutions on the first page use `itertools` in the dupe target, if you have a better one, then please do add it of course

Comment: @Chris_Rands, You misunderstand my point. Adding my solution for **this specific use case** makes no point on the more general question. Because it doesn't answer the question.. While here it does. Don't get me wrong, I'll keep my answer as a community wiki. I just fail to see how someone can look at the answers there and come up with the solution I have below. *Or* how I can add my answer there.

Comment: @jpp you can re-open this if you want

Comment: @jpp,@chris_Rands  UPdated the question abit

Comment: @sayan_sen, I've rolled it back. You shouldn't change your question materially once you've had an answer / answers. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

For your specific data structure, you can use `itertools.chain` with a ternary condition:

```
from itertools import chain

x = [0.29839835, [734, 805, 679, 758], 'A']

res = list(chain.from_iterable([i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for i in x))

[0.29839835, 734, 805, 679, 758, 'A']
```

For a **generalised** solution, see [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
l = [0.29839835, [734, 805, 679, 758], 'A']
a = list()
def flatten(l, a):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            flatten(i, a)
        else:
            a.append(i)
    return a
print(flatten(l, a))
#[0.29839835, 734, 805, 679, 758, 'A']
```